# Options for MeCab Japanese tokenizer on iOS?

Tags: ios, tokenize, cjk, mecab

I'm using the iPhone library for MeCab found at https://github.com/FLCLjp/iPhone-libmecab .  I'm having some trouble getting it to tokenize all possible words.  Specifically, I cannot tokenize "吉本興業" into two pieces "吉本" and "興業".  Are there any options that I could use to fix this?  The iPhone library does not expose anything, but it uses C++ underneath the objective-c wrapper.  I assume there must be some sort of setting I could change to give more fine-grained control, but I have no idea where to start.

By the way, if anyone wants to tag this 'mecab' that would probably be appropriate.  I'm not allowed to create new tags yet.

UPDATE:  The iOS library is calling mecab_sparse_tonode2() defined in libmecab.cpp.  If anyone could point me to some English documentation on that file it might be enough.

Comment: "吉本興業" is a proper noun and one word. You are asking like to tokenize "Facebook" into "face" and "book". Is that really you want?

Comment: @akky Depending on what the purpose of the tokenization is, there can be good reasons to split 吉本 and 興業. For example, when the tokenizer is used to build the index of a search engine, users generally expect to find documents that contain 吉本興業 even if they search for 興業 only. Unless a full substring-search enabled index is used, this means you need to split compound nouns into their parts.

Comment: It's no easy task, but you could try to adapt the iPhone-libmecab to use the newer, state-of-the-art [Unidic](https://osdn.net/projects/unidic/) dictionary instead of Ipadic; if I recall correctly (it's been a year since I read the research), it allows you to tokenise by "Short Unit Words" or "Long Unit Words".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing iOS-specific in this. The dictionary you are using with mecab (probably ipadic) contains an entry for the company name 吉本興業. Although both parts of the name are listed as separate nouns as well, mecab has a strong preference to tag the compound name as one word.

Mecab lacks a feature that allows the user to choose whether or not compounds should be split into parts. Note that such a feature is generally hard to implement because not everyone agrees on which compounds can be split and which ones can't. E.g. is 容疑者 a compound made up of 容疑 and 者? From a purely morphological point of view perhaps yes, but for most practical applications probably no.

If you have a list of compounds you'd like to get segmented, a quick fix is to create a user dictionary for the parts they consist of, and make mecab use this in addition to the main dictionary.

There is Japanese documentation on how to do this [here](http://mecab.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mecab/doc/dic.html). For your particular example, it would involve the steps below.

1. Make a user dictionary with two entries, one for 吉本 and one for 興業:

   ```
   吉本,,,100,名詞,固有名詞,人名,名,*,*,よしもと,ヨシモト,ヨシモト
   興業,,,100,名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,こうぎょう,コウギョウ,コウギョウ
   ```

   I suspect that both entries exist in the default dictionary already, but by adding them to a user dictionary and specifying a relatively low specificness indicator (I've used `100` for both -- the lower, the more likely to be split), you can get mecab to tend to prefer the parts over the whole.
2. Compile the user dictionary:

   ```
   $> $MECAB/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index  -d /usr/lib64/mecab/dic/ipadic -u mydic.dic -f utf-8 -t utf-8 ./mydic
   ```

   You may have to adjust the command. The above assumes:

   1. Mecab was installed from source in `$MECAB`. If you use mecab installed by a package manager, you might have difficulties finding the `mecab-dict-index` tool. Best install from source.
   2. The default dictionary is in `/usr/lib64/mecab/dict/ipadic`. This is not part of the mecab package; it comes as a separate package (e.g. [this](http://code.google.com/p/mecab/downloads/detail?name=mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz&can=2&q=)) and you may have difficulties finding this, too.
   3. `mydic` is the name of the user dictionary created in step 1. `mydic.dic` is the name of the compiled dictionary you'll get as output (needs not exist).
   4. Both the system dictionary (`-t` option) and the user dictionary (`-f` option) are encoded in UTF-8. This may be wrong, in which case you'll get an error message later when you use mecab.
3. Modify the mecab configuration. In a system-wide installation, this is a file named `/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/ipadic/dicrc` or similar. In your case it may be located somewhere else. Add the following line to the end of the configuration file:

   ```
   userdic = home/myhome/mydic.dic
   ```

   Make sure the absolute path to the dictionary compiled above is correct.

If you then run mecab against your input, it will split the compound into its parts (I tested it, using mecab 0.994 on a Linux system).

A more thorough fix would be to get the source of the default dictionary and manually remove all compoun nouns you want to get split, then recompile the dictionary. As a general remark, using a CJK tokenizer for a serious application in production mode over a longer period of time usually involves a certain amount of dictionary maintenance (adding/removing entries) regularly.

Comment: Thank you @jogojapan, your explanation is excellent.  We are making custom flashcards for language learners based on their own texts, so I don't think user dictionaries will be the way to solve this for us.  Right now they are split up on our webserver as per my question, but when tokenizing on the iPhone it does not work the same.  I will look into whether our server is using a different dictionary.  However, it is actually probably a mistake on the learners' parts to think that, as in your example, "Facebook" should be "face" "book".

Comment: That was akky's example, not mine. Anyway, learners may want to split a compound because it is easier for them to remember that way. Rather than face+book, I'd rather compare it to "New York". That's certainly one word, not two, but anyone who sees it for the first time, will be glad to realise that it is a combination of an adjective and the name of another city. Ultimately, that is why it's spelled with a space in between, after all. But let me understand: Your learners can put spaces between words on a flashcard, and you hope mecab will come up with the same tokenization as the learner?

Comment: @arsenius Or are you simply saying that mecab on the server generates output different from mecab on the phone?

Comment: The second.  Therefore, not knowing that it is actually a proper noun, users sometimes interpret it as two words. I think this is true of all of our languages, and not just Japanese.  I was told that our server is using a Python version of mecab.  (By the way, I had no idea what that word meant above, I was just told that the iPhone wasn't splitting it in two)

Comment: @arsenius Oh I see. Then, if the same versions of mecab are used on server and phone, a different dictionary must be installed. As mentioned in the answer, the dictionary is separate from the implementation. There is the ipadic, as well as the jumandic and possibly others. Making sure the same dictionary is used on both ends will be important.

Comment: Great answer. In the example CSV input to the user dictionary, how come you left the second and third arguments (the left/right "context IDs") empty? What do they do?

Comment: @AhmedFasih According to the Japanese documentation, these arguments are integers and used to specify the id of the internal status when the word is encountered in left-to-right mode (second argument) and right-to-left mode (third argument). If you have access to the built-in system dictionary and you want your new entry to be treated in the same way internally as an existing word from the system dictionary, you can copy the ids from the existing entry. Otherwise leave them empty, and the dictionary creation tool will assign them automatically (not sure how it does that).